# Lotus-like succulent. What plant is this?

Tags: identification, plant-care, succulents

The plant is very small and looks similar to one I have that is quite bigger compared to this little fella. Is this Echeveria? What is the care and soil needs for this plant? Both the plants are in 4" pot.

[image]

Update:

[image]

Similar plant, is this same?
[image]
[image]

Comment: Lovely pictures, Echeveria or a sempervivum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is Echeveria!
But I'm  not sure which variety, maybe 'Fleur Blanc' or 'Lola'.

You can use a ready made succulents mix for the soil. 
But it's best to make your own simple mix.
Start with good quality potting soil as the base then add extra agricultural sand (washed and graded coarse granular sand)  and a hand full of grit to allow air flow to the roots.

It must be well draining and light on fertiliser.
It should not be easily compacted as that would restrict oxygen flow.

You can feed your plant during the summer growing season with a water soluble fertiliser. This would help the plant flower and grow healthy leaves.

NPK 5-5-5 would be a cautious amount to use as they can take higher levels then that.

Try to water from the bottom if your pots are indoors as water tends to stagnate on the crown leading to rot.

keep them above 7c during winter. As long as they are cool they will not need any water.
But if the leaves show stress(shrivelled leaves), you can water them a little bit.

Note the leaves could get damaged if the naturally occurring coating is rubbed/washed off.

As always it is advised to use clean water not hard water to avoid mineral buildup.

They love full sun. Indoors the leaves could turn brown and dry if it's very hot for them.

Comment: so requirement is same for every Echeveria?

Comment: This would be the standard way to care for succulents and cacti. Some plants may require specific conditions but if you need a good starting base I would recommend the above answer.

Comment: @seedelicious What is agricultural sand?  I did a google search, but nothing came up.   Can you describe it or give a different name for those unfamiliar with this product?   Is it another name for coarse sand?

Comment: Agricultural sand is sand that is suitable for agricultural purposes, (washed and graded granular sand with no salts)