# What to do with the babies of this Echeveria?

Tags: plant-care, succulents, transplanting

This succulent is drying from the bottom and has developed many babies under it.

[Lotus-like succulent. What plant is this?](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/49102/lotus-like-succulent-what-plant-is-this)

When I was r-potting it, the babies were really tiny and now they are growing and getting bigger. These pics were taken some days ago and now the plant has lost some more leaves at the bottom and those babies are somewhat bigger.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Should I let it grow? How do I separate them without damaging the mother and babies? And if I re-pot the babies, should I keep the succulent mix mist all the time until the roots develop?